# True or False?: There are infinitely many continuous functions $f$ for which $\int_0^1f(x)(1-f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was going through CMI 2019 paper; I stumbled upon the statement:

For $f:R\rightarrow R$, there are infinitely many continuous functions $f$ for which $\int_0^1f(x)(1-f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}$.

My approach is, we can write $f(x)(1-f(x))=\frac{1}{4}-(f(x)-\frac{1}{2})^2$.

Now, we can write $\int_0^1f(x)(1-f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}-\int_0^1(f(x)-\frac{1}{2})^2dx$

$\Rightarrow \int_0^1(f(x)-\frac{1}{2})^2dx=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.

So, there must be only one function satisfying the condition. However, the official answer says the statement is true. Am I missing something?

Comment: is f allowed to be complex valued?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that $f:R \rightarrow R$

Comment: Then there are infinitely many as $f\big|_{[0,1]}\equiv \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: Your work is correct

Comment: Even I feel it is correct. It is just that CMI is a reputed institute for mathematics so I want to be sure that I have not ignored some important detail

Comment: This is a trick question, more about legal nitpicking than mathematics.

Answer (score 14):

Your argument has missed the fact that the domain of $f$ is the entire real line, not only the interval $[0,1]$. You have correctly shown that the restriction of $f$ to $[0,1]$ must be $1/2$, but there are infinitely many continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with this property.

Comment: Domain for f is entire real line, but we are calculating integral from 0 to 1. And in any case $f(x)(1-f(x)) \le \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: yes, but computing the integral over $[0,1]$ instead of $R$ doesn't mean that the domain of $f$ changes from $R$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: True, but we can write $f(x)(1-f(x))=\frac{1}{4}-(f(x)-\frac{1}{2})^2$ for all x in R.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example based off of @Mike_Hawk's answer. Let

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2} && \text{ for }x\leq 1\\
\left(\frac{1}{2}-b\right)x+b && \text{ for }x>1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

It is clear that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ but that

$$\int_0^1 f(x)(1-f(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}$$

Since $b$ is a free variable, there are infinitely many continuous functions which satisfy your condition.